# Kernel module still in use afther executing `$ echo 3 > /dev/tlc5947` (reference counting error)

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, reference-counting

Hellow I'm tring to learn writing kernel modules and device drivers. As a begginig I decided to start by making a driver for my tlc5947 led matrix. From simple kernel module with parameters I moved to char device driver but I'm having hard time with resource reference counting. Whole day I have been playing the restart game with my PI and still can't figure from where the bug is comming ...

This is the module header:

```
#include <linux/gpio.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/stat.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>

#ifndef _TLC5947_LED_MATRIX_H
#define _TLC5947_LED_MATRIX_H

#define TLC5947_GPIOS 3
#define TLC5947_LEDS 24
#define TLC5947_MAXPWM 4096
#define GPIO_HIGH 1
#define GPIO_LOW 0
#define TLC5947_NAME "tlc5947"
#define CONST_PARAM S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH

ushort tlc5947_chips = 255;
ushort tlc5947_data = 255;
ushort tlc5947_clock = 255;
ushort tlc5947_latch = 255;

static struct gpio tlc5947[TLC5947_GPIOS] = {
    {.gpio = -1, .flags = GPIOF_OUT_INIT_HIGH, .label = "TLC5947 DATA"},
    {.gpio = -1, .flags = GPIOF_OUT_INIT_HIGH, .label = "TLC5947 CLOCK"},
    {.gpio = -1, .flags = GPIOF_OUT_INIT_HIGH, .label = "TLC5947 LATCH"},
};

static dev_t tlc5947_numbers;
static int tlc5947_major_number;
static int tlc5947_first_minor = 0;
static unsigned int tlc5947_minor_count = 1;
static struct file_operations tlc5947_file_operations;
static struct cdev* tlc5947_cdev;
static int tlc5947_file_opened = 0;

static int tlc5947_file_open(struct inode* inode, struct file* file);
static ssize_t tlc5947_file_write(struct file* file, const char __user* buffer, size_t buffer_length, loff_t* offset);
static int tlc5947_file_close(struct inode* inode, struct file* file);
static int is_tlc5947_param_set(ushort* tlc5947_param, const char* tlc5947_param_name);
static int __init tlc5947_init(void);
static void __exit tlc5947_exit(void);

#endif
```

The source:

```
#include "tlc5947_led_matrix.h"
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>
#include <linux/gpio.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/stat.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/errno.h>

module_param(tlc5947_chips, ushort, CONST_PARAM);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(tlc5967_chips, "Number of tlc5967 chips that are chain connected.");
module_param(tlc5947_data, ushort, CONST_PARAM);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(tlc5967_data, "Number of gpio pin on wich DATA signal is connected (BCM Enum).");
module_param(tlc5947_clock, ushort, CONST_PARAM);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(tlc5967_clock, "Number of gpio pin on wich CLOCK signal is connected (BCM Enum).");
module_param(tlc5947_latch, ushort, CONST_PARAM);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(tlc5967_latch, "Number of gpio pin on wich LATCH signal is connected (BCM Enum).");

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Ivo Stratev");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Basic Linux Kernel module using GPIOs to drive tlc5947");
MODULE_SUPPORTED_DEVICE(TLC5947_NAME);

static int tlc5947_file_open(struct inode* inode, struct file* file) {
    if(tlc5947_file_opened == 1) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Fail to open file /dev/%s\n", TLC5947_NAME);
        return -EBUSY;
    }
    tlc5947_file_opened = 1;

    return 0;
}

static ssize_t tlc5947_file_write(struct file* file, const char __user* buffer, size_t buffer_length, loff_t* offset) {
    char data[10];
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned long copy_ret = copy_from_user(data, buffer, buffer_length);
    if(copy_ret) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Error while copying data\nCalling copy_from_user reurned%ld\n", copy_ret);
        return copy_ret;
    }
    data[0] -= '0';
    i = tlc5947_chips * TLC5947_LEDS - 1;
    gpio_set_value(tlc5947_latch, GPIO_LOW);
    while(1) {
        unsigned char bit = 11;
        while(1) {
            gpio_set_value(tlc5947_clock, GPIO_LOW);
            gpio_set_value(tlc5947_data, (data[0] & (1 << bit)) ? GPIO_HIGH : GPIO_LOW);
            gpio_set_value(tlc5947_clock, GPIO_HIGH);
            if(bit == 0) {
                break;
            }
            bit--;
        }
        if(i == 0) {
            break;
        }
        i--;
    }
    gpio_set_value(tlc5947_clock, GPIO_LOW);
    gpio_set_value(tlc5947_latch, GPIO_HIGH);
    gpio_set_value(tlc5947_latch, GPIO_LOW);

    return copy_ret;
}

static int tlc5947_file_close(struct inode* inode, struct file* file) {
    tlc5947_file_opened = 0;

    return 0;
}

static int is_tlc5947_param_set(ushort* tlc5947_param, const char* tlc5947_param_name) {
    int is_255 = (*tlc5947_param) == 255;
    if(is_255) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Parameter %s value not setted when loading the module\n", tlc5947_param_name);
    }

    return is_255;
}

static int __init tlc5947_init(void) {
    int init_ret = 0;
    init_ret |= is_tlc5947_param_set(&tlc5947_chips, "tlc5947_chips");
    init_ret |= is_tlc5947_param_set(&tlc5947_data, "tlc5947_data");
    init_ret |= is_tlc5947_param_set(&tlc5947_clock, "tlc5947_clock");
    init_ret |= is_tlc5947_param_set(&tlc5947_latch, "tlc5947_latch");
    if(init_ret) {
        return -EINVAL;
    }
    tlc5947[0].gpio = tlc5947_data;
    tlc5947[1].gpio = tlc5947_clock;
    tlc5947[2].gpio = tlc5947_latch;
    init_ret = gpio_request_array(tlc5947, TLC5947_GPIOS);
    if(init_ret) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Unable to request GPIOs!\nCalling gpio_request_array returned %d\n", init_ret);
        return init_ret;
    }
    init_ret = alloc_chrdev_region(&tlc5947_numbers, tlc5947_first_minor, tlc5947_minor_count, TLC5947_NAME);
    if(init_ret) {
       printk(KERN_ERR "Could not allocate device numbers\nCalling alloc_chrdev_region returned %d\n", init_ret);
        return init_ret;
    }
    tlc5947_major_number = MAJOR(tlc5947_numbers);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Device major number is %d. Use $ sudo make device\n", tlc5947_major_number);
    tlc5947_cdev = cdev_alloc();
    tlc5947_cdev->owner = THIS_MODULE;
    tlc5947_file_operations.owner = THIS_MODULE;
    tlc5947_file_operations.open = tlc5947_file_open;
    tlc5947_file_operations.release = tlc5947_file_close;
    tlc5947_file_operations.write = tlc5947_file_write;
    tlc5947_cdev->ops = &tlc5947_file_operations;
    init_ret = cdev_add(tlc5947_cdev, tlc5947_numbers, tlc5947_minor_count);
    if(init_ret) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Failed to add device numbers to struct cdev\nCalling cdev_add returned %d\n", init_ret);
        return init_ret;
    }

    return 0;
}

static void __exit tlc5947_exit(void) {
    cdev_del(tlc5947_cdev);
    unregister_chrdev_region(tlc5947_numbers, tlc5947_minor_count);
    gpio_free_array(tlc5947, TLC5947_GPIOS);
}

module_init(tlc5947_init);
module_exit(tlc5947_exit);
```

And the makefile:

```
target = tlc5947
driver = tlc5947_led_matrix

obj-m := $(target).o
$(target)-objs := $(driver).o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
    rm -f /dev/$(target)

activate:
    insmod $(target).ko tlc5947_chips=8 tlc5947_data=17 tlc5947_clock=27 tlc5947_latch=22

remove:
    rmmod -rf $(target)
    modprobe -rf $(target)

device:
    mknod /dev/$(target) c 243 0
    chmod 777 /dev/$(target)
```

Comment: I'm not sure where the reference counting problem is, but here are the other problems I noticed in your code: (1) `tlc5947_init` does not clean up after itself when it returns an error. (2) `tlc5947_file_write` has a buffer overrun on `data[]` if the user tries to write more than 10 bytes at once. (3) This is more of a programming style issue, but the contents of `"tlc5947_led_matrix.h"` looks like it belongs in the main module .c file.